# Sending mail with attachment in Google Apps script throws exception

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to attach a html document (from Google drive) in my mail using the below piece of code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var message = 'Hi';
    var fileId ='0B0azXoe_2qFTzNYa1p5eUd0c2s'; // My html document ID
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
    var subject = 'Saved Transaction Cleardown logs';
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob('mail', 'application/vnd.google-apps.document', 'stc.html');  // I am not sure about the above line, Hope that is where i am wrong
      MailApp.sendEmail('XXXXXXX@gmail.com', subject,
                    message,
                    { attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.HTML), blob],
                       name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
                    });
}
```

Exception received:
We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

Comment: Have you try to wait a bit and try again later ?

Comment: Yes, but still getting the same error :(

Comment: When you're debugging, is the error occur on the same line of code or is it some random line which crash ?

Comment: Hi Pierre, It occurs on the same line

Comment: Please tell which line cause the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more appropriate way to achieve your objective:

```
function myFunction() {
    var message = 'Hi';
    var fileId ='0ByLGhvnaCIQsZXcteeRWd0e344eFE'; // My html document ID
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
    var subject = 'Saved Transaction Cleardown logs';
      GmailApp.sendEmail('someone@gmail.com', subject,
                    message,
                    { attachments: [ file],
                       name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
                    });
}
```

Change the id of the html file. 
You don't even need to get the blob. Check [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))